# django python manage py syncdb doesn't add tables to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, pycharm

I just started learning Django yesterday, and I'm having a problem when I trying to add new tables to my MySQL server:

I created a model in models.py (lets say the app name is "article" and the model name is "Article"). I ran `syncdb` lots of times with different examples in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` (like "article" and "article.models") but it doesn't add the tables.

(Of course I see the other tables like "auth_group", "auth_group_permissions" etc.. but not the table of the Article model I created.)

model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date publish')
    likes = models.IntegerField()
```

the project structure:

[image]

python version: 2.7.9

the db:
[image]

Comment: what version of django are you using? Besides, could you include your project layout, your models.py code and relevant settings.py sections?

Comment: Try to add the project name: `HelloMySQL.article`.

Comment: in the INSTALLED_APPS you must specify your app name. Assuming this is article, how did you configure DATABASES?

Comment: and more, after syncdb is called, is there a *.sqlite3 file? in this case you have a wrong database configuration(and the behaviour is the default one).

Comment: When I added the project name HelloMySQL.article it send me an error: ImportError: No module named article
where should I look for the *.sqlite3 file? anyway, I think the db is well configured, that's because the image I added on the topic.

Comment: I see a migrations folder in your project... Did you run makemigrations after creating the model class? There should be table creation commands in one of the migration files.

Comment: I just did it, and it worked! thanks a lot!! can you explain me why it worked and why with the 10 tutorials I read it didn't mention?

Comment: run python manage.py `makemigrations` and see the output in the migrations folder. `syncdb` is getting obsolete soon.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the new Django migrations is available here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/

once you have your new app and added it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py, you do the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

this will create a python file in the app migrations folder. It will realize the changes, new additions...etc to apply to your database and then you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

no more `syncdb`, it will be obsolete soon